# Exclude certain period of data in FB Prophet

Tags: r, facebook-prophet, prophet

Is it possible to exclude certain period of data (e.g covid period) in FB Prophet and plot the forecasted data over that period rather than using actual values? I'm trying to see the pattern in the charts if covid period was excluded/included.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should exclude those values in your original model.

Before running your model, just filter your original dataset to not have the covid period data.

filter(date =< as.Date("2020-03-01"))